# Xcode 4.2 symbol navigator mucked up

Tags: ide, xcode4.2

Out of the blue, the "symbol navigator" (second icon from the left in the navigator pane) started just giving me access to a single .h file.  The "project navigator" continues to display the entire project.

I've tried flipping things back and forth, restarting Xcode, etc, to no avail.  It's stuck on that one file.

The one clue I have is that the .h file is the only .h in the project's second target, a test target.  But I don't see any way to select a target (vs the project) for navigation by the symbol navigator (and I definitely didn't "play with" any settings that might affect this.)

Any ideas?  Navigation already sux in Xcode 4, and I don't need to be further hamstrung by this problem.

**Additional Info:** I notice that Cmd/Click on a symbol defined in the project produces "Symbol not found", when the symbol is most definitely present (and is found by search).

**Sigh** Mysteriously started working again.  Only possible clue is that we were dinking with the scheme at one point (related to another problem).

**1/9/12** Just as mysteriously returned.  This happened after updating from CVS, however.

**1/10/12** Figured out that the problem is with Xcode's "indexing" stuff, and found that you can delete the index (and other "derived data" stuff) and force it to be rebuilt in Organizer/Projects.  Did that, and the index was rebuilt when I next opened the project.  However, now the Navigator only lists a few files in a test target, so actually a step backwards.

Comment: Same issue in Xcode 4.3.3 :-(

Answer (score 3):

Well done! Thanks a lot!

I was having issue of the same origin, specifically here are the symptoms:
1) Cmd + Click on method calls, .h files, defined names leads to "Symbol not found" message
2) Code highlighting in editor doesn't paint the above mentioned objects in colours
3) Symbol Navigator (Cmd + 2) is just empty

Deleting derived data for affected project in Organizer/Project and reopening the project solved the issue. When you reopen the project reindexing is automatically executed and it works again!

Pity that XCODE is so buggy. :-(

Once againg, many thanks to Hot Licks!