# Duplicate classes in Xcode Symbol Navigator

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode7

My project has several targets. Some of these targets include the same file. I think this is causing them to appear more than once. Am I doing something wrong? Is there anything I can do to not show the duplicates?

[image]

Comment: I have had problems with that pane.  If you don't get linking errors, it's probably just another Xcode bug.  You can always double check though, in the compile section of Build Phases for your target.

Comment: Looks related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681818/. I tried deleting my ´Derived Data´ folder and restarting Xcode as suggested there. After indexing has completed I still get one additional duplicate per target.

Answer (score 0):

Been struggling with this also, I have about 10 targets and it makes the symbol navigator very fiddly to use.

May have a workaround that works for some situations, depends how complex your file structure is and how often you switch targets.  For me I'm usually only working on one target at a time and every swift file is included in every target (and therefore appears 10 times).  If I assign all the files to the single target I'm working on, the duplicate classes in the symbol navigator disappear.

1. Go to the project navigator (CMD-1)
2. Select all the swift files that are shared across multiple targets
3. Show the file inspector (in the utilities area, RHS, CMD-ALT-1)
4. Under 'Target Membership' select only the target that you are currently working on.
5. Rebuild and you should find the symbol navigator dupes are gone.

You have to repeat this process every time you switch targets otherwise you get linker errors when you build, but for me that's a minor hassle I'm prepared to pay to make the symbol navigator useable again.

Comment: Hopefully this is fixed in an update. This is a pain, but thanks for the work around.